# Local Coldfusion Server - htaccess and port

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

How do I get from this: http://127.0.0.1:8500/pagename.cfm

to this: http://localhost/pagename

on my local ColdFusion server?

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to get things partially working by resetting Coldfusion to the correct MAMP locations. The issue I'm having now is that it doesn't seem as though the actually Coldfusion is running (I could be wrong) as none of the <cfinclude>s are loading on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall ColdFusion. Make sure you have a "Default" website set up using IIS, Apache or whatever your web server is. Defaults are usually set to port 80. Then reinstall ColdFusion. Do not select the option to use CF's built-in web server, assuming you're running your own. Even if you do install CF's own one it doesn't matter at you can disable the server after.

Load the Web Configuration Tool that comes with CF and check it has an entry for your Default website. If not you need to add one. Select your web server from the list and then the website you want to use ColdFusion with.

Comment: Okay. So I'm close. I didn't realize there was a different set up needed when using MAMP.

Config Directory: /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache
Server Binary: /Applications/MAMP/bin/apache2/bin/httpd 
Server Control Script: /Applications/MAMP/bin/apache2/bin/apachectl

I am going to need to work on getting my local htaccess file working. Would there be a reason my css files aren't loading? I can go to localhost/index.cfm and see all of the html, but nothing is formatted...

Thanks!